# Undefined response when using JEST to do API testing

Tags: reactjs, axios, babel-jest

I keep getting undefined error when running test on my API function

```
Expected: "Mock Jedi"
    Received: undefined

      12 |     const result = await fetchAdmin();
      13 |     console.log(result);
    > 14 |     expect(result).toEqual('Mock Jedi');
         |                    ^
      15 |   });
```

My API is in this file:

```
AdminTable.js

export const ADMIN_URL = '/admin_management/list/';

export const fetchAdmin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      ADMIN_URL
    );
    return response.data.results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
};
```

and my test file is like this:

```
app.test.js

import mockAxios from 'axios';
import { fetchAdmin } from '../pages/AdminTable';

jest.mock('axios');
mockAxios.post.mockResolvedValue({ data: { results: 'Mock Jedi' } });

describe('fetchAdmin', () => {
  test('return data', async () => {
    const result = await fetchAdmin();
    console.log(result);
    expect(result).toEqual('Mock Jedi');
  });
});
```

I was expecting that the received results to also be "Mock Jedi" since the mock axios is set as
`{ data: { results: 'Mock Jedi' } }`

**!!!FIXED!!!**
First mistake i made was not letting jest.mock to do a post request. Changes to app.test.js

```
jest.mock('axios',()=>({  
  post: jst.fn(),
}));
```

But after implementing that there is a `typeError: axios.create not a function`. Which lead me to my axios file

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});
```

I then found the solution to mock jest based on my axios file instead. The changes were done to the test file

```
import { fetchAdmin } from '../pages/AdminTable';
import axios from '../api/axios';

jest.mock('../api/axios', () => ({
  post: jest.fn(),
}));
mockAxios.post.mockResolvedValue({ data: { results: 'Mock Jedi' } });

describe('fetchAdmin', () => {
  test('return correct data', async () => {
    const result = await fetchAdmin();
    expect(result).toMatch('Mock Jedi');
  });
```

Comment: Where does `axios` come from in your `AdminTable.js` module? What exactly does the `import` statement look like?

Comment: @Phil it is like that on top `import axios from '../api/axios';`  in my `AdminTable.js` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a mock for `axios` but nothing for `axios.post`.

I would recommend something like this

```js
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn(),
}));
```

or if you're using `axios.create()` somewhere in the pipeline...

```js
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  create: jest.fn(() => ({
    post: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

Now Jest knows that `mockAxios.post()` is mocked function and your `fetchAdmin` code will call it.

---

You can also verify the call was made with the expected arguments with

```js
expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ADMIN_URL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but when i implement that line i received a different error. TypeError: _axios.default.create is not a function

Comment: @Mehbenmeh you aren't using `axios.create()` anywhere in your question so I can only assume there's more to this than you've shown

Comment: yes there was more which i didnt think that matter to this issue. I have found the solution! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You are returning `response.data.results` in your `fetchAdmin` function, but in your test, you are expecting the result to be 'Mock Jedi'. Instead, you should expect `response.data.results` to be equal to 'Mock Jedi'.

Use:

```
expect(result).toEqual({ results: 'Mock Jedi' });
```

Comment: OP has mocked Axios to resolve with `{ data: { results: "Mock Jedi" } }`. The `fetchAdmin` function returns `response.data.results` (a string)

Comment: What phil said was right. My API is returning response.data.results. therefore my object that i mock is { data: { results: 'Mock Jedi' } } and the expected result should be just 'Mock Jedi'. Thank you for your input thou!